# hp exstream object was not found error

Tags: hp-exstream

My application was working fine, there was no error when I built package file last time. Today I made a small change, then I built package file. This time I got an error coded EX002573. 
Details said, Required object (Library Rule OI 5452 used by "Page component XXXX") is not included in the application. Other objects referring to this one are invalid.

If I click on the error, following info is showing up.
Report: The object in question was not found in the database.
Action: Update the object or remove it from the application.

The change I made is a very simple placement and dynamic placement changes. For some pages mentioned in the error, I didn't even touch them. Where's the issue? Any input will be appreciated.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Try to show some code and what you tried to find the issue.

Comment: Sounds to me like there is rules on one of your pages that doesn't exist anymore. Goto that page and check it top to bottom for the rule.

Comment: After exhausting all the options(mentioned by others) and still if it doesn't work, I would recommend to take a database backup copy and running a database maintenance. You need to have admin access to do that. Running a database maintenance will eliminate most of these issues.

Answer (score 1):

This means that Exstream is not able to find any reference in its database for whatever reason.

Sometimes just simple re-saving of objects mentioned in the log and refreshing the Design Manager will solve the issue. If not, you will need to redesigned objects that its complaining about (table, page, paragraph...)

If you have access to the Exstream database you can check "COMPONENT_X_RULE" table "IO" column for some details.